# iOS Background Fetch with Remote Notifications

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, background-fetch

Is it possible to use both background fetching and silent remote notifications at the same time to maximize the number of background activity? Apple says they put limits on both but using both would be a work around to such limits right? If I set the background fetch interval to the minimum and then send a silent notification every 15 minutes, how would this work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set both. But remember that the background fetch interval is just an indication to iOS. iOS determines when background fetches occur based on its own criteria (including the phone being plugged in or not, being unlocked or not, doing any other work that woke up the CPU and radios, etc.).

Likewise, delivery of silent remote notifications is not guaranteed.

Remember that in any case, you want to minimise power consumption while in the background. All those restrictions Apple sets are there for this reason. Trying to bypass them has a cost.